# Problem installing Adobe Indesign using Wine

Tags: wine, adobe

I'm trying to use Adobe InDesign CS4 with Wine. This version of ID is rated Gold on WineHQ. I've installed some libraries required according to this website. Still I get many errors:

```
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32dee8,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW flags 0x08080132 ignored
fixme:font:GetCharacterPlacementW classes not implemented
fixme:clipboard:AddClipboardFormatListener 0x10060: stub
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
fixme:wincodecs:ComponentFactory_CreateEncoder ignoring vendor GUID
fixme:wincodecs:PropertyBag_Write Application tried to set the unknown option L"FilterOption".
fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 0x32deb0
fixme:win:LockWindowUpdate (0x10060), partial stub!
fixme:win:LockWindowUpdate ((nil)), partial stub!
fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
fixme:win:LockWindowUpdate (0x10060), partial stub!
fixme:win:LockWindowUpdate ((nil)), partial stub!
wine: Unhandled exception 0xc06d007e in thread 9 at address 0x7b83b4ee (thread 0009), starting debugger...
Unhandled exception: 0xc06d007e in 32-bit code (0x7b83b4ee).
Register dump:
...
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10, using Wine 1.7.

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever fix the issue?

Comment: @KarlMorrison No, unfortunately not. I use Windows on virtualbox when I need AID.